# on-screen keyboard, communication between Toplevel and Tk on pythons tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to create my own little on-screen keyboard but failed, when I tried to get the buttons insert text in the entry widget...

I imagine, there could be a solution like `self.text_in.insert`, but I can't call that function from the keyboard-class...

the other solution I could imagine is to send the text of the pressed button to the id of the entry-widget, but therefor I don't know any code...

is there a better solution than one of those?
How would you solve this problem?
I really need help here.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        ttk.Button(self, text="show Keyboard", command=lambda: Keyboard(self)).pack()
        self.text = tk.StringVar(value="")
        self.text_in = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.text)
        self.text_in.pack()

class Keyboard(tk.Toplevel):
    
    OPENED = False
    NAME = "- Keyboard -"
    NUM = ({"1":{"text":"1", "info":"6", "width":1},
            "2":{"text":"2", "info":"7", "width":1},
            "3":{"text":"3", "info":"8", "width":1}})
    CHAR = ({"A":{"text":"A", "info":"a, A", "width":1},
                "B":{"text":"B", "info":"b, B", "width":1},
                "C":{"text":"C", "info":"c, C", "width":1}})
    
    def __init__(self, master):
        if not Keyboard.OPENED:
            Keyboard.OPENED = True
            print("keyboard opened!")
            tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
            self.title(self.NAME)
            self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)

            self.keyb_nb = ttk.Notebook(self)
            self.keyb_nb.pack()

            self.num_tab = ttk.Frame(self.keyb_nb)
            self.createPad(self.num_tab, Keyboard.NUM, 5)
            self.keyb_nb.add(self.num_tab, text="123")

            self.char_tab = ttk.Frame(self.keyb_nb)
            self.createPad(self.char_tab, Keyboard.CHAR, 7)
            self.keyb_nb.add(self.char_tab, text="ABC")

    def createPad(self, master, pad:dict, max_col):
        self.co_count = 0
        self.ro = 1
        for button in pad.keys():
            self.b = ttk.Button(master, width=6*pad[button]["width"], text=pad[button]["text"], command=self.bclicked(button))
            if self.co_count >= max_col:
                self.ro = self.ro + 1
                self.co_count = 0
            self.b.grid(row=self.ro, columnspan=pad[button]["width"], column=self.co_count)
            self.co_count = self.co_count+pad[button]["width"]

    def bclicked(self, button:str):
        ### this is the callback of the button "button", given as parameter
        ### here the code which solves my problem should be entered. but if there is a other option then this function also can be deleted
        pass

    def close(self):
        Keyboard.OPENED = False
        self.destroy()
        print("keyboard closed!")


root = MainWindow()
root.mainloop()
```

thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please try to simplify this code a bit. We don't really need all of those characters and numbers _for the purpose of this question_.

Comment: I cant simplyfiy it more than that, because then it will not stay debug-ready

Comment: Does the on screen keyboard only have to act on the single entry, or will you want to use it for multiple entry and/or text widgets?

Comment: for multiple, actualy for the last focused widget, wich accepts text-input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use emulated events, like this:

```
entry.focus_force()
entry.event_generate("<Key-A>")
```

Comment: is it possible, that the Tk will not loose focus, when the Toplevel gets the focus?
and when the toplevel is clicked once, it will never loose focus, until it's closed?

Comment: I tried something like this:
                             `self.master.text_in.focus_force()
                         self.master.text_in.insert(index=tk.INSERT, string=button)`

but the it always inserts the text of the last created button of the active notebooktab, beacuse untill the buttons command is called, the `button` variable changed because the for-loop continued running

Comment: You can use `button.bind('<Button-1>', evtHandler)`, evtHandler example: `def evtHandler(evt): self.master.text_in.insert(index=tk.INSERT, string=evt.widget.cget('text'))`

Comment: do you have an idea, how i can get the id of the last active widget wich supports textinput? for example if i had a `tk.Text` widget and a `tk.Entry` widget in my Mainwindow and want to insert the text in that wiget, wich has had the focus at last...

Comment: `root.focus_get()` returns current focus if there is one